How to Read Image Tags in VB.NET Using the Description Section
I am trying to extract image tags from the description section of an image using VB.NET. The image tags are stored in the description section:

Tags I saved:
StyleShootsModel=sam001;StyleShootsAspectRatio=2_3;StyleShootsPreset=Jacqueline;StyleShootsProducts=21FKA00012;StyleShootsFraming=CRP;StyleShootsEquipment=StyleShoots Live ();

I've attempted the following sample code:
Public Shared Function GetDMetaTagFromImage(ByVal path As String) As DateTime
    Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Using myImage As Image = Image.FromStream(fs, False, False)
            Dim tagsValue As String = ""

            Dim tags = myImage.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault(Function(pi) pi.Id = &H9C9E)
            If tags IsNot Nothing Then
                tagsValue = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(tags.Value)
            End If
            Return tagsValue
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

However, the code doesn't seem to work as expected. How to correctly extract the image tags from the description section using VB.NET?

Read the notes here: Extra null Char between characters in metadata encoding a JPG image. There's also a reference to a previous, similar, question

@Jimi I'm having trouble identifying my mistake with the code I've tried below; despite my efforts, I'm still unable to understand it. I'm new to this, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

'Public Enum PropertyItemType As Short
PropertyTagTypeByte = 1
PropertyTagTypeASCII = 2
PropertyTagTypeShort = 3
PropertyTagTypeLong = 4
PropertyTagTypeRational = 5
PropertyTagTypeUndefined = 7
PropertyTagTypeSLONG = 9
PropertyTagTypeSRational = 10
End Enum'

Using myImage As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
Dim propItems As PropertyItem() = myImage.PropertyItems
Dim propItem As PropertyItem = propItems.FirstOrDefault(Function(pi) pi.Id = &H9C9E)
If propItem IsNot Nothing Then
' Decode the property value and remove any null characters
tags = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value).Replace(vbNullChar, "").Trim()
End If
End Using

My suggestion was to always check the PropertyItem's Type before processing it. Anyway, the Type of that PropertyItem is byte[] (Byte()), hence the use of Encoding.Unicode.GetString() is correct. What is not correct is that, since the resulting value is a null-terminated String, you're trying to return a DateTime object in your function. If you stored a date in string format, then you have to get the Value as string, strip the null-terminator, then convert the string to a DateTime object with, e.g., DateTime.TryParse() -- If you have Option Strict OFF, set it ON right away

@jimi, could you please review the code I posted below

As @Jimi As mentioned in the comment, I tried using the Bitmapframe and successfully read all tags.
  Using stream = File.OpenRead(path)
        Dim frame = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None)
        Dim metadata = DirectCast(frame.Metadata, BitmapMetadata)
        Dim Keywords = metadata?.Keywords
        If Keywords IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each keyword As String In Keywords
                Console.WriteLine(keyword)
            Next
        End If
    End Using

Also I tried using the package mentioned below, but its works perfectly fine for single tags
Imports MetadataExtractor
Imports MetadataExtractor.Formats.Iptc

Public Shared Function GetKeywordsFromImage(ByVal path As String) As String
    Dim directories As IEnumerable(Of MetadataExtractor.Directory) = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(path)
    Dim keywordsValue As String = ""

    Dim iptcDirectory = directories.OfType(Of IptcDirectory).FirstOrDefault()
    If iptcDirectory IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim tag = iptcDirectory.GetString(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords)
        If tag IsNot Nothing Then
            keywordsValue = tag
        End If
    End If

    Return keywordsValue
End Function


If you have saved the Tags using the System's dialog, then the strings are Unicode encoded (UTF16-LE). Hence, to extract the string and remove the trailing null char, you have Encoding.Unicode.GetString(propItem.Value).TrimEnd(ChrW(0)). Then split the content based on the default separator (;)

@jimi I tried multiple ways still   consistently receive a null value in the propItem field

There are no Fields here, just local variables. If propItem is null, there's no 0x09C9E property set. How did you store the data in that PropertyItem? Are you sure you're inspecting the right image? -- You should probably post the image somewhere (inside a ZIP archive, to avoid possible modifications), so it can be tested -- BTW, you should not post your attempts as answers here, since the code doesn't solve the issue. Modify the question instead, adding the tests you have performed. And, please, include all details about the procedure used to set the Value(s) of the PropertyItem(s)

Moreover, while debugging your code, read the content of the Image's PropertyItems and specify, in the question's body, what Properties this collection contains

I took a look at the image you posted. GDI+ doesn't recognize that piece of metadata. Maybe because it was set in a non-Windows System (the Software Property items says Capture One 16 Macintosh). If you're comfortable with package you're using (you actually didn't post a link to that NuGet (?)), go with it. If you're interested, System.Windows.Media.Imaging can read that information. Pass a file stream to BitmapFrame and then read the Metadata.Keywords property.

For example: using stream = File.OpenRead([Image Path]) dim frame = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None) dim tags  = DirectCast(frame.Metadata, BitmapMetadata)?.Keywords end using

thats great answer @jimi ,Since I'm keeping several tags, I can read every tag simply repeating the keywords.   Using stream = File.OpenRead(path)             Dim frame = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None)             Dim metadata = DirectCast(frame.Metadata, BitmapMetadata)             Dim Keywords = metadata?.Keywords             If Keywords IsNot Nothing Then                 For Each keyword As String In Keywords                     MessageBox.Show(keyword)                 Next             End If         End Using
